# Can Flutter replace React in the PERN stack?

Tags: flutter, dart, react-fullstack

I want to make a full-stack application. Is the PEFN stack viable? Also, if I follow along with a PERN tutorial, will I be able to figure out how to hook up the Flutter App with the Postgres, Express, Node in the same way as react?

Comment: Any stack is viable if you know how to use it.

Comment: Thanks. Will I be able to learn how to use it by following along a tutorial meant for the PERN stack? I already know Flutter, Postgres and Node, I've just never hooked them together to form the stack.

Comment: Yeah. Don't go from `stack` per se.
I mean you could wire up Django with Flutter in all the glory. `Stack` names are overrated.

Comment: Sure, it's just that I would prefer to use Node, Express and Postgres at the moment. It's not the best question, I know. It's just that there aren't any good books or tutorials for SQL-based full stack flutter dev. I hope I can figure it out.

Comment: You have good books on Express and Postgres, right. And Flutter docs are good.
There is nothing special with wiring up them together.